# Predicting car prices with machine learning - advice on best model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, supervised-learning

I am trying to predict the price for cars using the following DataFrame `data`. Data types: model, transmission, and fuel type as `obj`, the rest as `float`/`int`.

The full dataset contains ~6500 samples (only `data.head()` listed here)

```
    model   year    price   transmission    mileage fuelType    tax mpg engineSize
0   Bolt    2016    16000   Manual          24089   Petrol      265 36.2    2.0
1   Bolt    2017    15995   Manual          18615   Petrol      145 36.2    2.0
2   Bolt    2015    13998   Manual          27469   Petrol      265 36.2    2.0
3   Bolt    2017    18998   Manual          14736   Petrol      150 36.2    2.0
4   Bolt    2017    17498   Manual          36284   Petrol      145 36.2    2.0
```

I start by dropping all duplicates and encoding the categorical variables:

```
# Drop duplicates
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep="first")

# Categorical variable encoding
cat_features = ["model", "transmission", "fuelType"]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoded = data[cat_features].apply(encoder.fit_transform)
data = data.drop(cat_features, axis=1)
data = pd.concat([encoded, data], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    model transmission fuelType year    price   mileage tax  mpg    engineSize
0   1     1            3        2016    16000   24089   265  36.2   2.0
1   1     1            3        2017    15995   18615   145 36.2    2.0
2   1     1            3        2015    13998   27469   265 36.2    2.0
3   1     1            3        2017    18998   14736   150 36.2    2.0
4   1     1            3        2017    17498   36284   145 36.2    2.0
```

Following the scikit-learn documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html), I tried regression using Lasso, ElasticNet, Ridge, and SVR.

I got the best results using the Ridge regression (see code below) with R^2 of 0.79 and MSE of 2941.73. However, my success criteria is predicting the price within a certain range of the actual price (e.g. +/- 1000).

Even with the Ridge model below, most predictions don't make the cut. Do you have any ideas how I could optimize the regression? Have I made any mistakes in the Ridge regression below or with the hyperparameters? Are there more appropriate models for this case?

Ridge:

```
X = data.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
y = data.iloc[:, 4]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

std_slc = StandardScaler()
pca = decomposition.PCA()
ridge = linear_model.Ridge()

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("std_slc", std_slc),
                        ("pca", pca),
                        ("ridge", ridge)])

n_components = list(range(1,X.shape[1]+1,1))

parameters = dict(pca__n_components=n_components,
                      ridge__solver=["auto", "svd", "cholesky", "lsqr", "sparse_cg", "sag", "saga"],
                      ridge__alpha=np.linspace(0, 1, 11),
                      ridge__fit_intercept=[True, False])

clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, scoring='r2', verbose=1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_ridge = clf.predict(X_test)

print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred_ridge))) 
print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred_ridge))
```

Output:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 56 candidates, totalling 280 fits
2941.734786303254
0.7909623313908631
```

Voting Regressor:

```
eclf = VotingRegressor(estimators=[ 
    ('ridge', linear_model.Ridge()),
    ('lasso', linear_model.Lasso()),
    ('elasticnet', linear_model.ElasticNet())
    ])

#Use the key for the classifier followed by __ and the attribute
params_eclf = {'ridge__solver': ["auto", "svd", "cholesky", "lsqr", "sparse_cg", "sag", "saga"],
        'lasso__selection': ["cyclic", "random"],
        'elasticnet__selection': ['cyclic', 'random'],
        'ridge__alpha': np.linspace(0, 1, 10),
        'ridge__fit_intercept': [True, False]}

grid_eclf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=eclf, param_distributions=params_eclf, cv=3, n_iter=250, verbose=1, scoring='r2')

grid_eclf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_eclf = grid_eclf.predict(X_test)

print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred_eclf))) 
print(r2_score(y_test, y_pred_eclf))
```

Output:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 250 candidates, totalling 750 fits
3082.2257067911637
0.7705191776922907
```

Comment: Always you will have limitation due to your dataset. Of course, if your data is poor, irregular, and without good patterns to learn, your model will not be very good (as your case)... it seems you have not a huge number of samples, that's a critical problem in machine learning because you can't generalize. To improve, I would recommend you: more data, feature engineering, evaluate more models (maybe random forest regressor,...). Finally, check in kaggle some problems of care price predictions because for sure you will find ideas or good inputs.

Comment: Thakns for the suggestions. Just to be clear, the whole dataset I am working with has ~6500 samples

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 3):

I've been dealing with a similar task before and judging by my personal experience:

- RMSE is outlier sensitive. You may cheat a bit by excluding extreme prices (and/or check out MAE instead).
- Categorical features like model aren't ordinal: label encoding is not so great in this case. Mean target encoding might improve the results. As a side effect, fuel type/gearbox features might turn out to be redundant.
- Linear models, KNN and SVR weren't performing so well, random forest and gradient boosting were the best (as they often are), single decision tree had an acceptable result as well;

(This is not the exact same dataset however so YMMV.)